# Use of icons inside a JAR in GWT UiBinder template

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder

In my GWT application I also use SmartGWT library for some user interface elements.
Recently I had the idea of replacing the text for some GWT Buttons (like "refresh" or "save") with an icon from SmartGWT's icon set, for example the refresh icon in **/com/smartclient/theme/graphite/public/sc/skins/Graphite/images/actions/refresh.png**

I tried to make the icon available in my UiBinder template with the qualified name:

```
    <ui:image field="refreshIcon" resource="/com/smartclient/theme/graphite/public/sc/skins/Graphite/images/actions/refresh.png" />
```

and use it for a PushButton:

```
    <g:PushButton ui:field="refreshButton" styleName="{style.Buttons}">
        <g:upFace image="{refreshIcon}" />
    </g:PushButton>
```

Unfortunately that does not work, eclipse has nothing to complain but when running the application I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [MonitoringTool] - No com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle$Source annotation and no resources found with default extensions
```

How can I use the bundled icons in referenced **smartgwt.jar** library for my PushButtons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute is named `src`, not `resource`:

```
<ui:image field="refreshIcon" src="/com/smartclienttheme/graphite/public/sc/skins/Graphite/images/actions/refresh.png" />
```

As a side note, it doesn't matter where the image comes from provided it's on the classpath: GWT loads *everything* from the classpath, whether it's in a JAR or folder doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I tried src, too, but ended up with eclipse telling:
Resource /com/smartclienttheme/graphite/public/sc/skins/Graphite/images/actions/refresh.png is missing

Comment: Remove the first "/" and hopefully that will work! I've had that issue when referencing resources from within a jar.

Comment: Removing the first / doesn't work either.
Am I missing something I have to do prior to accessing the image by its qualified name?

Comment: It looks like setting the src attribute references the image as a URL. Is it possible that there's a resources class in the jar that points to the image? Something like here (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Using_an_external_resource).

Comment: @RaynCGN Eclipse is wrong: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5267 It should work.

Comment: @filip-fku No, the `src` attribute value is turned into the value for a `@Source` annotation in the implicit `ClientBundle` generated by UiBinder. Check it out with `-gen` when compiling or running DevMode.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: Excellent, thank you! That's the solution, something I never would have thought of.

I set the severity level of UiBinder's "Missing resource file" to "Warning", ignore this warning and now it works with the qualified name and the first "/" removed.